# Animated gif doesn't work when application runs

Tags: c#, wpf, animated-gif

I downloaded WPFAnimatedGiff.dll from codeplex. And here is the problem:
I'm trying to implement the giff inside of tab item. The giff is actually a circular progress bar, so I'm trying to simulate loading process of the tab item similar to google chrome progress bar. I inserted the image, and it is visible in designer, but it does not show up when I run my application. Also when I insert image somewhere else in grid, it does show up.
Here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFHotel.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFHotel"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:WPFHotel.Database"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com" />


 <TabItem Tag="PB1" Header="Rezervacije" Name="Reservations" BorderBrush="Black" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14">
            <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                            
                        <TextBlock Text="Rezervacije" Margin="5,2,0,0" />
                        <Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="Images/468.gif" Stretch="None" />                           

                    </StackPanel>                        
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
</TabItem>
```

Tried to google for the solution but could not find anything useful, so I hope some one can help me here.
**Edit:** Just to mention that when I insert the image like this:

```
<Image Source="Images/CircleBar.gif" />
```

It is shown when application runs but there is no spin/animation.

Comment: What is `build action` of the image in the properties pane? Set it to `Resource`

Comment: It is set to Resource.

Comment: Tried your code and worked fine for me. Make sure your image name is correct and it is inside Images folder

Comment: I checked it, and it's all fine. In designer the image is right on it's place right next to tab item header, but when i run application there is just empty space where the image should be. Also i set the visibuility to visible, but it's the same effect. What confusing me the most is that the image is shown when i put it outside of tab item.

Answer (score 5):

There are two solutions

1. Create a UserControl and add in XAML in any grid of StackPanel
2. Design a WindowsForm , add animation controls on it and then call it in WPF code , But keep in mind you must set two properties of that animation control , one is its **StartPosition** and other **TopMOST = True**

Answer (score 0):

You can think to use another control for that

http://huydinhpham.blogspot.com/2011/07/wpf-loading-panel.html

Here is a code http://sites.google.com/site/huyphamproject/Home/LoadingPanelSample.zip

Notice, that you can simplify it as you need.

I hope that will help you to get rid of GIF in WPF.

Comment: Well I wanted to avoid using another control, and just make it simple with giffs. Thank's for the link anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could just take all the pictures in the gif, and then have those pictures each flash up individually. This may take some time, but it is a fool proof method that doesn't require too much coding knowledge.